# Format decimal places in print() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program for finding the sum upto nth term of the Leibniz Series.

I want to print answers on different lines correct upto 15 decimal places.

The code.

```
a=[]
for _ in range(int(input().strip())):
   n=int(input().strip())
   a.append(sum([(-1)**i/(2*i+1) for i in range(n)]))
print("\n".join(str(i) for i in a))
```

My output:

```
0.7604599047323508
0.77290595166696
```

Expected Output:

```
0.760459904732351
0.772905951666960
```

**NOTE-** I want to keep the code as minimal as possible

Comment: So you want to change `str(i)` to `"{:.15f}".format(i)`? That is actually your question?

Comment: Yes. That is that what I want to do. Any other method which doesn't include format() or join() method is welcomed.

Comment: what is your input for that output

Comment: Line separated integer values
2
10
20

Comment: @NakulParmar Accept the answer which helped you the most. Click the little tick below downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want,

```
0.7604599047323508
```

to be **rounded-off** upto 15 decimal places like this,

```
0.760459904732351
```

That's pretty **simple**:

```
i = 0.7604599047323508
print(i)
print("%.15f" % i)
```

Output:

```
0.7604599047323508
0.760459904732351
```

If you have number of *decimal* length less than 15. Then `0`s are added. Take a look,

```
x = 0.760459904732 #Less than 15

print(x)
print("%.15f" % x)
```

Output:

```
0.760459904732
0.760459904732000
```

**UPDATE:**

There is also the **built-in** function `round()` you can use that too. 
`round(value,places)`

Example:

```
>>> a=0.7604599047323508
>>> round(a,15)
0.760459904732351
```

For your code: *Using `print()`*

```
a=[]
for __ in range(int(input().strip())):
   n=int(input().strip())
   a.append(sum([(-1)**i/(2*i+1) for i in range(n)]))

for i in a:
    print("%.15f" % i)
```

Also why do you use `_` ? Use some other name instead. To know the purpose of `_` try this in your interpreter.

```
>>> a=10
>>> b=20
>>> a+b
30
>>> _
30
>>> a*10000
100000 variable name.
>>> _
100000
>>> a
10
```

`_` stores the most recent calculation in interpreter. `_` is used as a **throwaway** variable `__` is better than `_` I guess.

Comment: Why exactly did someone downvote my answer? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, `_` is used as a throwaway variable in python, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) for example, but many other soruces say the same. Plus you add a superfluous `for` cycle for printing

Comment: **`_` should be avoided `__` should be used** is mentioned clearly in the accepted answer. To avoid conflicts

Comment: True, but you should specify it in your answer instead of saying to use another name instead

Comment: *superfluous `for `* why do you say that? Explain

Comment: It can be replaced with `join` as in OP example (and my own answer :P ), although i don't know which one is faster (i guess `join` because it's a built in, but I'd have to try). The point is OP explicitly asks to keep code as minimal as possible

Comment: You use a `for` inside the join to get elements. I use them to  print. Do you really think mine is *superfluous* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148175/discussion-between-gionni-and-s-vishnu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to get exact precision

```
from decimal import *
for x in range (0,int(input())):
    s,n=Decimal('0'),int(input())
    for i in range(0,n):
        s+= Decimal(str(((-1)**i)/((2*i)+1)))
    print (s)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

`"\n".join("{:.15f}".format(i) for i in a)`